# Чем внешняя поразрядная сортировка отличается от обычной поразрядной сортировки?

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, терминология

Чем внешняя поразрядная сортировка отличается от обычной поразрядной сортировки? Алгоритмом?

пример из книги Искусство программирования. Том 3. Кнут:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что здесь означает  слово "внешняя" - задумывались?

Comment: @MBo Работа с файлами?

Comment: Думаю ответ нужно икать в лекциях у девчонок

Comment: Да. И алгоритм соответственно дорабатывается.

Comment: @MBo читал Кнута, не совсем понятен пример с лентами. Нет конкретики. Хотелось бы понять что нужно доработать в поразрядной сортировке, чтобы получить внешнюю поразрядную сортировку

Comment: Слово "внешняя" означает, что некоторые промежуточные данные сохраняются во внешнем хранилище и временно "теряются из виду", а когда нужны - подгружаются из внешнего хранилища.

Comment: @pythmy  Для учебной задачи - например, при MSB сделать десять файлов для каждой старшей цифры, распределить данные из начального большого файла, отсортировать каждый и т.д.

Comment: @MBo как я понял, изначально массив находится в одном большом файле. С помощью алгоритма MSD распределяем числа массива по 10 файлам исходя из старшего разряда числа. Затем применяем обычную поразрядную сортировку в каждом файле(сортируем последовательность чисел в файле) и на последнем шаге объединяем все файлы в один. так? Просто меня пример с лентами сбивает(Кнут 3 том) все кажется что не так.

Comment: @pythm В примере Кнута LSD - на мой взгляд, труднее понимать и отлаживать (промежуточные состояния неочевидны).

Comment: @MBo хорошо, спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При сортировке по MSD (сначала по старшей цифре) сделать десять файлов для каждой старшей цифры, распределить в них данные из начального большого файла.

Затем повторяем для каждого файла - если его размер невелик по сравнению с доступной оперативкой - выполняем обычную сортировку в памяти, иначе содержимое файла распределяем на десять файлов второго уровня по второй цифре и так далее.

Отсортировав мелкие файлы, сливаем их в более крупные до тех пор, пока не останется единый отсортированный файл.